# "Fixed size array" error on insert One-To-Many

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf

I am working on a little project with EF6. Whenever I want to insert some data with a `OneToMany` or `ManyToMany` realtionship, I encounter the error:

> InvalidOperationException: An item cannot be added to a fixed size Array of type 'Shared.ProjectStep[]'

I googled a bit and found the suggestion to replace `ICollection` on navigational properties with `IList` as well as changing the serialization through `Add Service Reference`, but none of this worked.

My entities (a few fields are omitted, because they shouldn't pose a problem):

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "Shared")]
public class Project
{

    public Project()
    {
        this.ProjectSteps = new List<ProjectStep>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<ProjectStep> ProjectSteps { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "Shared")]
public class ProjectStep
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

I have defined the relationship through `Fluent API` as following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasMany<ProjectStep>(p => p.ProjectSteps).WithRequired(ps => ps.Project).Map(m => m.MapKey("Project"));
}
```

I have a `PMSDatabaseConnector` which delegates the operations to my `PMSContext : DbContext`

This context is created with

```
public PMSContext() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "PmsDb")
{
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

And finally my method to insert a `ProjectStep`

```
public void InsertProjectStep(ProjectStep ps)
{
    this.projectSteps.Add(ps);
    this.SaveChanges();
}
```

Whenever I now execute

```
ProjectStep ps = new ProjectStep();
ps.Description = "test";
ps.EndDate = new DateTime();
ps.Project = service.FindProjectById(8);
ps.StartDate = new DateTime();
service.InsertProjectStep(ps);
```

(create a new `ProjectStep`, set a few fields as well as connection to the `Project`), I get the exception

> InvalidOperationException: An item cannot be added to a fixed size
>   Array of type 'Shared.ProjectStep[]'.

Adding this line

```
this.projects.Find(ps.Project.ID).ProjectSteps.Add(ps);
```

as first line in the `InsertProjectStep` method like this:

```
public void InsertProjectStep(ProjectStep ps)
{
    this.projects.Find(ps.Project.ID).ProjectSteps.Add(ps);
    this.projectSteps.Add(ps);
    this.SaveChanges();
}
```

, I get the error

> 'Multiplicity constraint violated. The role
>   'Project_ProjectSteps_Source' of the relationship
>   'PMSDatabaseConnector.Project_ProjectSteps' has multiplicity 1 or
>   0..1.'

I am really lost on this topic. I tried everything I could find, but nothing fixed the first error.

Can someone please help me understand why these error occur, as well as how to fix them?

Comment: Why is ProjectSteps an IList, and not an ICollection?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro in the question op states "I googled a bit and found the suggestion to replace ICollection on navigational properties with IList"

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I started with `ICollection`, but due to googleing that specific error, I changed it to `IList` which didn't help.

Comment: what happens if you replace the .Map function with the .HasForeignKey function for the mapping (or no further mapping at all)?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro If I change the mapping, then I can't even retrieve a `Project` from database.

Comment: what is the error you are getting then?

Comment: Without any mapping I get `Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'ProjectStep_Project_Target' of the relationship 'PMSDatabaseConnector.ProjectStep_Project' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.` And with `ForeignKey` mapping I get `'The foreign key component 'Project' is not a declared property on type 'ProjectStep'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.'` FK-Mapping: (`modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasMany<ProjectStep>(p => p.ProjectSteps).WithRequired(ps => ps.Project).HasForeignKey<Project>(p => p.Project);`)

Comment: ".HasForeignKey<Project>(p => p.Project);" - the FK has to be the same type as the PK of the referenced type (int in your case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the general recommendation for EF collection navigation properties is to use `ICollection<T>` type, it doesn't work well with WCF serialization because it allows WCF deserializer to assign `T[]`. Same for `IList<T>` (`T[]` "implements" both interfaces as well as many others).

The solution is to not use interface, but *concrete* type `List<T>`:

```
[DataMember]
public virtual List<ProjectStep> ProjectSteps { get; set; }
```

Another way which requires more coding is to use explicit backing field:

```
private ICollection<ProjectStep> projectSteps;

[DataMember]
public virtual ICollection<ProjectStep> ProjectSteps
{
    get { return projectSteps; }
    set { projectSteps = value is ProjectStep[] ? value.ToList() : value; }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but now I get `Multiplicity constraint violated` on `this.projectSteps.Add(ps);`. Is the insert method theoretically right?

Comment: Single question per post please. Anyway, these are kind of mutually exclusive. If you do `this.projects.Find(ps.Project.ID).ProjectSteps.Add(ps);`, then don't do `this.projectSteps.Add(ps);`. And vice versa. If `ps.Project` instance is not attached to the context, I would suggest using the first method (`this.projects.Find(ps.Project.ID).ProjectSteps.Add(ps);`).